# How to save the passed parameter in the URL for use in different controller in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In one page I have an DataTable.
when clicked upon a user, the user Id gets passed as url value 
    usersInfo?getid=1

I have a controller like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "users/userInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"getId"})
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getClientStat(@RequestParam(value="getId", required = true) String getId) {

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
     long clientId=0;
    clientId=Long.parseLong(getId);
    Client client=clientService.getClientById(clientId);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("userName", user.getName() + " " + user.getLastName());
    modelAndView.addObject("userId", user.getId());
    modelAndView.addObject("id", client.getName()+ " " + client.getLastName());
    modelAndView.setViewName("users/userInfo");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And then I use the passed object id which has the name and last name to show the user name.

Then on the opened users/userInfo page I have a button which sends to another page to fill out a form.
The question is : How do I save the fields of these form to the database, but for the client whose id I have in the controller.

How do I pass this value on ? 
Or is there a better more logical way to do this ?
I am fairly new at using Spring , so I apologize in advance if something is unclear but I would really appreciate some guidance.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @PathVariable with addAttribute

```
@RequestMapping(value = "users/edit/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getClientStat(@PathVariable(value="userId", required = true) String userId) {

    //Use the userId to find user information and pass
    modelAndView.addAttribute("id", userId)
    modelAndView.setViewName("users/edit");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

In your view, you can add the userId as hidden field
`<input type="hidden" name="userId" value={userId} />`, depend on the view you're using thymeleaf OR jsp

Comment: But I already have that. I get the id from the url, 
After this controller returns to a View, which is users/userInfo.
 Then there I want to be able to go to a different site, fill out a form and have the userId part of the submission, so that I save the values for that user.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank yoou! I will follow that logic and I hope I get it to work !

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget to rate me and if you've further question, i'm always here for you.

Comment: Definitely. How do I rate you ?

Comment: Click on the top arrow beside my answer. Thanks and hope it works!